# Presto - reducing an array of structs

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to reduce an array of complex types, however I'm running into a syntax error (maybe this isn't even supported?).

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:1: Unexpected parameters (array(row(count 
double,name varchar)), integer, 
com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.TypeSignatureProvider@16881774, 
com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.TypeSignatureProvider@1718b83d) for 
function reduce. Expected: reduce(array(T), S, function(S,T,S), 
function(S,R)) T, S, R
```

The complex type is defined as `counters array<struct<count:double,name:string>>` in the table. I have tried selecting `reduce(counters, 0, (state, counter) -> state + counter.count , s -> s)` and `reduce(counters, 0, (state, counter) -> state + counter['count'] , s -> s)`, however neither work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct (tested with Presto 0.205):

```
presto:default> desc t;
  Column  |                  Type                  | Extra | Comment
----------+----------------------------------------+-------+---------
 counters | array(row(count double, name varchar)) |       |


presto:default> select * from t;
                  counters
--------------------------------------------
 [{count=1.0, name=a}, {count=2.0, name=b}]

presto:default> select reduce(
        counters, 0,
        (state, counter) -> state + counter.count,
        state -> state) from t;
 _col0
-------
   3.0
(1 row)
```

You tagged the question `prestodb` and `amazon-athena`. If you are trying this on Athena, please bear in mind that [Athena is based on Presto 0.172](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html) (which was released April 2017)

Comment: can I concat strings in the same manner, instead of summing integers? as soon as I change the return value of the reduce's input function to string it gives me that `Unexpected parameters` error